# Getting the PDE using Laplace equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Hey guys I need help on one of the past midterm question that I came across. I am pretty sure I got (a) right. But if it is wrong could you please let me know. But its (b) and (c) that I got in trouble with. Any help or solution to those would be really helpful. I have a midterm in 2 days I just want to get confident in all this.

Question:

Let D be the inﬁnite vertical strip $D = (0 \leq  x \leq  1, -\infty < y < \infty)$:

(a) show that the function $u(x, y) = sin(\alphax)sinh(\alphay)$ satisﬁes the (two-dimensional version of the) Laplace equation in D for any real value of the constant . For which value(s) of $\alpha$  does the above proposed solution satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions $u = 0$ on the boundary of D?

b) consider the following PDE problem:

$\bigtriangleup u = g(x, y)$ on D

$u = h$      on the boundary of D

where $\bigtriangleup$ denotes the two-dimensional Laplace operator $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} $
Is the problem well-posed? Justify your answer using the results of item (a).

(c) Taking inspiration for item (a), guess a solution of the Laplace equation in D which satisﬁes the Neumann boundary conditions $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$ on the boundary of D. What can you conclude about the well-posedness ofthe following PDE problem?

$\bigtriangleup u = g(x, y)$   on D

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = h$ on the boundary of D:

My attempt:

(a)

So I know the laplace equation is $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$

So I found $u_{xx} = - \alpha^2 sin(\alpha x)sinh(\alpha y)$ and $u_{yy} = \alpha^2 sin(\alpha x)sinh(\alpha y)$

So therefore $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ if I plug it into the equation.

Now to find the values of $\alpha$

we know $u(0, y) = sin(0)sin(\alpha y) = 0$ and $u(1,y) = sin(\alpha)sinh(\alpha y)$

Therefore $sin(\alpha) = 0 \Rightarrow $ only when $\alpha = k \pi$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$

now b and c I get confused.

Please help out I would be really greatful thank you.

Comment: For part a) I assume you mean $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing strange in b).

Hint for c).

$$
\int_D g=\int_D\Delta u=\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}=\int_{\partial D}h
$$